# setState is not defined with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working with reactJS and I am trying to use setState so that i can use that state to determine which way the graph needs to rotate but I get an error saying `'setState' is not defined  no-undef`. Do I need to have a constructor to initialize the state?

Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {rotate, setRotate} = setState(false)
        return (
            <div className="custom-container">
                <Tree 
                    data={data} 
                    height={600} 
                    width={1000}
                    svgProps={{transform: 'rotate(${rotate ? "90" : "0")'}} 
                />
                <button onClick={() => setRotate(!rotate)}>Rotate</button>
            </div>
        );
    }    
}
```

Comment: Although the error message is probably because you haven't imported `setState`, you can't use `setState` in class components.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: @GuyIncognito You mean `useState` right? @kr419 read https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: In class components as you have, [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is a member of the `React.Component` class and should be called using the context of that class, via `this.setState()`.

Comment: Right, useState. This is some kind of strange combination of hooks and setState and invalid syntax.

Comment: You're mixing syntaxes really badly, please read through the React documentation thoroughly so you can understand how to use it's different pieces.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use, "useState" instead of setState,
'useState' is used for having a state in functional components, you will have to convert class component to function component as below and then use 'useState'

```
export default function App() {

        const [rotate, setRotate] = React.useState(false)
        return (
            <div className="custom-container">
                <Tree 
                    data={data} 
                    height={600} 
                    width={1000}
                    svgProps={{transform: 'rotate(${rotate ? "90" : "0")'}} 
                />
                <button onClick={() => setRotate(!rotate)}>Rotate</button>
            </div>
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also try this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
      rotate: false
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="custom-container">
                <Tree 
                    data={data} 
                    height={600} 
                    width={1000}
                    svgProps={{transform: 'rotate(${rotate ? "90" : "0")'}} 
                />
                <button onClick={() => this.setState({ rotate: !this.state.rotate})}>Rotate</button>
            </div>
        );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to use useState();

Make sure you import useState at the top first and also use function component instead of the class component :

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';



function App() {
    const [rotate, setRotate] = useState(false)
    return (
        <div className="custom-container">
            <Tree 
                data={data} 
                height={600} 
                width={1000}
                svgProps={{transform: 'rotate(${rotate ? "90" : "0")'}} 
            />
            <button onClick={() => setRotate(!rotate)}>Rotate</button>
        </div>
    );
```